# Go through all the files within a range in groups of 24

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, range

I have the following loop

```
for file in range(10000):
    ...
```

This will go through all the files within this range and do something.

Instead, I would like it to still go through all "files", but in groups of 24. In other words, the first 24 "files" should be considered to do the specific calculations (storing that value in a list), then the next 24 files, and so on, till the 10000 "files" are considered.

The number 10000 is just for the sake of the question.

Comment: seems like you need nested for loop. Outer `for` with step of 24 and inner for between i, i+24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with the % modulo operator:

```
processing = 0

for file in range(1000):
    if file % 24 == 0:
        processing += 1
    #Process your stuff, use processing var to store it
    #Like list_of_result[processing] or a dict_of_results[str(processing)] etc
```

It says, here, that each time the rest of file divided by 24 is equal to 0, then you change your processing set counter variable value.

So processing will be equal to 1 for the first 24, 2 for the following 24, etc...

Another way with that same % operator but not counter:

```
results = []

for file in range(1000):
    if file % 24 == 0:
        if file != 0:
            #Store your slice of results in the main results list
            results.append(tmp_results.copy())
        #Clear the 24 batch result list
        tmp_results = [] #Or a dict

    #Process your stuff, store in in tmp_results
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a good use-case for the `grouper` recipe from [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). Note that `grouper` uses a fill value (`None` by default) to pad the last group if the total number of elements is not divisible by the group size.

Example:

```
>>> [list(g) for g in grouper(range(5), 3)]
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, None]]
```